# Gatling, Scala, regex and shortest match

Tags: regex, scala, gatling, shortest

I have a problem I cannot solve. I'm willing to capture a pattern with a regex depending on a variable and I want to get the shortest match (not the first occurence that matches but the last which is also the shortest)

Here is the gatling pseudo code

```
val rubriquesPath=Seq("toto","tata","titi","tutu")

.foreach(rubriquesPath,"rubrique"){
    exec(http("${rubrique}")
        .get("/" + "${rubrique}")
        .check(regex("""URLPage":"(.+?)".*?"path":"/${rubrique}/""").saveAs("tms")))
    .exec(http("TMS " + "${rubrique}")
        .get("${tms}"))
}
```

Data sample (which is in fact a single line)

```
{"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4579.json?cache=60000","BOName":"Test","path":"/toto/"},
{"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4774.json?cache=60000","BOName":"Test","path":"/tata/"},
{"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4745.json?cache=60000","BOName":"Test","path":"/titi/"},
{"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4799.json?cache=60000","BOName":"Test","path":"/tutu/"}
```

In this example, I would like to capture the URLPage value depending on a variable in a sequence
I.E

- for toto: preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4579.json?cache=60000
- for tata: preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4774.json?cache=60000

> regex("""URLPage":"(.+?)".*?"path":"/${rubrique}/"""

matches and captures the string in italic below which is logical but that's not what I'm trying to do (get the pattern in bold)

For tata

> "URLPage":"*preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4579.json?cache=60000*","BOName":"Test","path":"/toto/"},
>           {"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"**preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4774.json?cache=60000**","BOName":"Test","path":"/tata/

For tutu

> "URLPage":"*preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4579.json?cache=60000*","BOName":"Test","path":"/toto/"},
>       {"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"preprod.test.com/page/ac73b/4774.json?cache=60000","BOName":"Test","path":"/tata/"},
>       {"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"preprod/test.com/page/ac73b/4745.json?cache=60000","BOName":"Test","path":"/titi/"},
>       {"displayName":"Bienvenue","URLPage":"**preprod/test.com/page/ac73b/4799.json?cache=60000**","BOName":"Test","path":"/tutu/"}

How can I properly do this?

Thanks

Jérôme